# error when parse json

Tags: ios, json, swift, parsing

I want to make a get request but I get error.

```
public static func get_coupons(_ api_token: String,_ lang: String,_ completion: @escaping (_ code:Int?)-> Void) {

        APIHelper.instance.data.removeAll()

        let url = "\(APIHelper.BASE_URL + APIHelper.API.COUPONS.rawValue)"

        var code:JSON!

        let headers = [
            "apitoken": "\(api_token)"
        ]

        Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, headers: headers).responseJSON { (response) in
            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                if let json = JSON(rawValue: response.result.value!){

                    code = json["code"]

                    if code.intValue == 200 {

                        print("Done")

                    }else{
                        print(code.intValue)
                    }

                    completion(code.intValue)
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
                return
            }
        }

    }
```

I tried the code above but I get this error.

> responseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}))

Comment: Please add your json format.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39286076/error-domain-nscocoaerrordomain-code-3840-invalid-value-around-character-0-us)

Comment: Your json format is incorrect. This is Format Error generally.

Comment: Try using https://github.com/cs4alhaider/Helper4Swift/blob/master/Helper4Swift/Classes/Classes/Helper4Swift.swift in line 24